# Matrix "divided" by a matrix. Can this be done?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, divisibility, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

So I am working on a problem and which basically looks like this

$- \frac{x^t A^{-1}x}{M x^TA^{-2}x}$ where $M$ is a scalar, $x$ is a vector and $A$ is a matrix (which in the actual problem is the hessian matrix and so is positive definite).

My question is, can the vector matrix products essentially "cancel" to leave me with just $\frac{1}{MA^{-1}}$?

Comment: Division isn't defined on matrices. We can take (some) matrix products and we can add (some) matrices, provided the dimensions match up. However, there is no division of matrices. Luckily, you aren't actually working with matrices because $x^t Ax$ is a scalar. So you can divide by the scalar $x^t Ax$ but you can't cancel out the vectors $x$ and $x^t$ because that operation is not defined.

Comment: Thought so. So what can I do in my case given that I have $- \frac{x^t A^{-1}x}{M x^TA^{-1}A^{-1}x}$? Is there any way I can simplify this?

Comment: Your original expression is a scalar. And what is the second expression?

Comment: I believe this will depend on the particular problem. For starters you say that $A$ is positive definite, so $A^k$ is positive definite for all integers $k$ as well, so you know the sign will be $-sign(M)$. I do not know off mind whether this reduces more nicely, just given the information you have.

Comment: $x^t A^{-1} x$ and $x^\top A^{-2} x$ are scalars, not matrices. Hence the original ratio is a ratio of scalars. $x^t$ and $x$ are not scalars, so cancelling them is impossible.

Comment: Your ratio is something called a [Generalized Rayleigh Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient#Generalizations)